# run chrome 30 without sandbox

Tags: google-chrome, testing, browser, cross-browser

I'm trying to run chrome 30, in Linux, from the command line (executing google-chrome file of the version downloaded and unpacked in a folder).

If i run it without the option  `--no-sandbox` the result is the following

> [24419:24419:1016/012228:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(142)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /home/user/user.browsers/chrome-30/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
>       ./chrome-30.sh: line 5: 24419 Aborted                 (core dumped) $CHROME_FOLDER/google-chrome

If I run it with the option `--no-sandbox`, following also this [procedure](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1346956&page=2) to configure it, the result is the error:

```
È stata creata una nuova finestra nella sessione corrente del browser.
[1016/012454:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(269)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

This last procedure works fine with chrome v31.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you have root access, you should set up the SUID sandbox as per [these instructions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md), and run without the `--no-sandbox` option.

If you don't have root access, you cannot set up a SUID sandbox and you have to use the `--no-sandbox` option, but only use it for testing because it is a security risk.
In your case, it looks like you tried running a new Chrome window with `--no-sandbox` while another session was already running (that's what the message in Italian says). Try closing the existing session before starting a new one. To close the existing session, find the Chrome icon in the system tray, right click it and choose `Exit`. If you don't see the system tray icon, you can also try `killall google-chrome` or `killall chromium`, depending on which version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
[24419:24419:1016/012228:FATAL:zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(142)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. 
Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. 
You need to make sure that /home/user/user.browsers/chrome-30/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755. 
./chrome-30.sh: line 5: 24419 Aborted (core dumped) $CHROME_FOLDER/google-chrome
```

...implies that the program was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

---

As per the discussion in [Issue 400842: Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=400842), if you have installed *Chromium v35* (or later) and your [cpu](/questions/tagged/cpu) doesn't have the [SSE2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2#CPU_support) instruction set, e.g. AthlonXP, Pentium III, etc, then *Chromium* can't be initiated successfully. All the new *Chromium* browsers from version **35** onwards need [SSE2](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/817-5477/epmpv.html). Any *Chromium* version earlier than **35** should run on such a system without any issue.

To enforce these measures, *Chromium* team have closed the issue as `Status: WontFix` and mentioned:

> If you really want to build Chromium without SSE2, you are welcome to apply your own patches and build your own browser however you like, but the Chromium project is not accepting patches to build without SSE2.

Further, this feature was successfully tested in *AMD Athlon 3400+* desktop with *Lubuntu 14.04.2* and *Chrome* seems to work fine. But on an older *AMD Athlon 1300* without `SSE`, *Chrome* now courteously displays a message that *"my hardware does not support it"*.

Answer (score 0):

In mac you can run the below command to run the chrome in sandbox mode. This will open the chrome and supress the security settings. This can be used for testing API's etc from angular or ionic

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=$HOME/chrome-in-sandbox-mode
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @IgorF. I have now added also the comments as additional context